# Critical values for maps in discrete topology

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

I am confused about a counterexample where Sard's theorem fails without second countability (taken from [this link](http://drorbn.net/index.php?title=0708-1300/Class_notes_for_Tuesday,_October_16)):

> Consider the real line with the discrete topology, a zero dimensional manifold, mapping via the identity onto the real line with the normal topology. Every point in the real line is thus a critical point and the real line has non zero measure.

I'm not sure why the critical points are everything now that we're mapping from discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Because any function is locally constant.